# MS Windows Batch: Use for loop with variable range and multiline commands

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, variables, range

I'm currently trying to convince the cmd.exe to execute a for loop from a *.bat with a variable range and multiline commands.

The code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set range=100,1,254
echo %range%

FOR /L %%i IN (%range%) DO (

set tempAddr=%subnet%.%%i
echo !tempAddr!

START /BELOWNORMAL /MIN "" "doSomething.bat" !tempAddr!

)
```

The problem:

cmd.exe always exits with the error [translated from german]:

```
")" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.
```

Is there a way to pass a variable range to the for loop in a batch like this?

Comment: If you omit the `START` line, do you still get an error?

Comment: In your provided code, you've omitted information, `%subnet%` is not defined within it. In addition, I wouldn't recommed that you try to start 154 batch files pretty much in parallel, _(regardless of the priority class your using)_. There is however nothing I can see in your provided code, which is related to the error message you've translated. Perhaps you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61930233/edit), to provide the rest of the script and the content of `doSomething.bat`